# Filtering data using multiple combo boxes

Tags: ms-access

I have followed a youtube tutorial but have the following run time error - 3075 - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[YPName] = 'CliveAND[ContactType] = 'Social Worker".

Clive is a 'YP Name' and Social Worker is a 'ContactType'

New to this and struggling. Any ideas where I am going wrong with the code?

YPName and ContactType are two fields in the database I want to filter by.
My combo boxes begin with the letters 'cbo'

```
Function SearchCriteria()
Dim YPName, strContactType As String
Dim task, strCriteria As String

If IsNull(Me.cboNameOfYP) Then
    YPName = "[YPName] like '*'"
Else
    YPName = "[YPName] = '" & Me.cboNameOfYP
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboContactType) Then
    strContactType = "[ContactType] like '*'"
Else
    strContactType = "[ContactType] = '" & Me.cboContactType & "'"
End If
strCriteria = YPName & "And" & strContactType
    task = "Select * from tblContactList where " & strCriteria
    Me.tblContactList_subform.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.tblContactList_subform.Form.Requery


End Function
```

Comment: You are missing closing apostrophe for Me.cboNameOfYP. Also, need a space before and after And operator: `" And "`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still struggling. I have changed the "AND" to " AND" but where should the closing apostrophe be? I have tried here -    YP = "[YPName] = '" & Me.cboNameOfYP '      still not working. Would really appreciate your input

Comment: `YPName = "[YPName] = '" & Me.cboNameOfYP & "'"`

Comment: Arrgghhh!! If you could provide me with the code that turns virtual kisses into real ones.........you would have hundreds of kisses. Thanks